# Push data from Salesforce to Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, salesforce, azureservicebus

i am looking for a solution for pushing data from salesforce to a azure service bus.

That's what I found:

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'InvoiceStatementUpdates';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Status__c, Description__c FROM Invoice_Statement__c';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 36.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;
```

With this code I can create a PushTopic in Salesforce. If there is any change on *Invoice_Statement__c*, this topic will send the Id, Name, Status_c and Description_c to all Clients.

The problem is that there is no guarantee that the Client is receiving all messages:

> Streaming servers don’t maintain any client state and don’t keep track
>   of what’s delivered. The client may not receive messages for a variety
>   of reasons...                   ([Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_stateless.htm))

So I wonder if I could send this information (Id,Name...) to a azure service bus. I found this "Help": https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Connecting_Force.com_to_Azure_Service_Bus_Part2
which did not solve my problem.

I wonder if one of you did have the same problem I do.

Hope someone could provide me (and all other guys and girls ;) ) a solution

Comment: see this https://seroter.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/using-the-windows-azure-service-bus-rest-api-to-send-to-topic-from-salesforce-com/ might help you?

Comment: thank you very much @KhadimAli . It's not exactly what I was looking for but it helped me a lot!